# Is there any way to keep text hashing consistent

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'm trying to create a simple method to create a new user with an encrypted password. The hashing result, however, does not seem to be consistent.

Apart from the user creation, I also did a method to change the user's current password, and the hashing works perfectly.

User create method:

```
public IActionResult Create(USERS uSERS)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DbSet<USERS> dbs = _dbContext.USERS;
            var sql = String.Format($@"INSERT INTO [USERS] ([emailId], 
            [password], [fullName], [role]) VALUES 
            ('{uSERS.emailId}', HASHBYTES('SHA1', '{uSERS.password}'), 
            '{uSERS.fullName}', '{uSERS.role}') ");
                if (_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql) == 1)
                {
                    ViewData["Msg"] = "New user created";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Msg"] = "Failed to update database!";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Msg"] = "Invalid information entered";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Change Password Method:

```
public IActionResult ChangePassword(PasswordUpdate pu)
        {
            var userid = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            var sql = String.Format($"UPDATE USERS SET password = HASHBYTES('SHA1', '{pu.NewPassword}') WHERE emailId='{userid}' AND password = HASHBYTES('SHA1', '{pu.CurrentPassword}')");
            if (_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql) == 1)
                ViewData["Msg"] = "Password successfully updated!";
            else
                ViewData["Msg"] = "Failed to update password!";
            return View();
        }
```

Manual SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO [USER] ([emailId], [password], [fullName], [role]) VALUES
('admin@test.com', HASHBYTES('SHA1','password'), 'ADMIN', 'Admin')
```

I always put 'password' as the user's password testing and here's the hashing result:

> Manual sql query: 0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8 
>   Using change password: 0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8 
>   Using create user: 0xFE5991ECC64EEC87AB37BDB0FF01F3976080D398

I think it's needless to say that I can log in with users that I manually create VIA manual query but not with the one I create using the method. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean? Hashing is consistent.

Comment: Is your input consistent ?

Comment: my input is always 'password' but somehow the result from the create method is not the same as the one from changepassword or manual query. Sorry for the unclear question

Comment: I've always just used SHACryptoServiceProvider in System.Security.Cryptography. That's always consistent.

Comment: Do you have trailing/leading spaces? Do you have lookalike characters?

Comment: No, I don't believe so

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is a difference between `varchar` and `nvarchar` (for example), but that doesn't seem to be the case in your example.

Comment: Please show us your unit tests for create and update.
My assumption is, you likely aren't passing "password" as password, when you create a user.

Comment: Avoid the issue by creating the hash in C# - it is a good idea to combine it with userName and use a salt anyway. In all cases, clean your input data first.

Comment: Okay this is embarrassing. Turns out I pass the input from the create method to a different model that receives different data type, hence they're hashed differently. Sorry, but I still appreciate the responses. Thanks for the wake up call @John